# White Cesium globe after upload GeoServer WMS layer

Tags: geoserver, wms, cesium, web-gis

I have a problem with my cesium globe. I have want to add a layer on the globe with a GeoServer WMS. The WMS layer appears but it turns the entire globe white. And without the WMS layer everything is normal. I have no error in the console (no CORS error), I don’t really understand what is happening. Does anyone know what to do? I don't know if the problem come from Cesium or maybe GeoServer?

Here the code I use and a picture of the problem.

```
Cesium.Ion.defaultAccessToken = 'my access token';

// Initialize the Cesium Viewer in the HTML element with the `cesiumContainer` ID.
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
    geocoder: false,
    animation: false,
    creditsDisplay: false,
    timeline: false,
    fullscreenButton: false,
    terrainProvider: Cesium.createWorldTerrain()
    
}); 

const provider = new Cesium.WebMapServiceImageryProvider({
    url : 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms',
    layers : 'scv:epneige_snowpark',
    transparent: true,
    format : 'image/jpeg',
    proxy: new Cesium.DefaultProxy('/proxy/')
});
const imageryLayer = new Cesium.ImageryLayer(provider);
viewer.imageryLayers.add(imageryLayer); 


    
viewer.camera.flyTo({
destination : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(6.568828, 44.922505, 3000),
orientation : {
    heading : Cesium.Math.toRadians(250.0),
    pitch : Cesium.Math.toRadians(-25.0),
}
});
```

[image]

More information about the geoserver logs :

03 juin 20:38:44 INFO   [geoserver.wms] -
Request: getMap
Angle = 0.0
BaseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
Bbox = SRSEnvelope[6.536865234374994 : 6.547851562500002, 44.901123046875 : 44.912109375]
BgColor = java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]
Buffer = 0
Clip = null
CQLFilter = null
Crs = GEOGCS["WGS 84",
DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295],
AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST],
AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Elevation = []
Env = {}
Exceptions = SE_XML
FeatureId = null
FeatureVersion = null
Filter = null
Format = image/jpeg
FormatOptions = {}
Get = true
Height = 256
Interpolations = []
Layers = [org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@1deeaf87]
MaxFeatures = null
Palette = null
RawKvp = {REQUEST=GetMap, FORMAT=image/jpeg, SRS=EPSG:4326, BBOX=6.536865234374994,44.901123046875,6.547851562500002,44.912109375, VERSION=1.1.1, STYLES=, SERVICE=WMS, WIDTH=256, HEIGHT=256, LAYERS=scv:epneige_snowpark}
RemoteOwsType = null
RemoteOwsURL = null
Request = GetMap
RequestCharset = UTF-8
ScaleMethod = null
Sld = null
SldBody = null
SldVersion = null
SortBy = null
SortByArrays = null
SRS = EPSG:4326
StartIndex = null
StyleBody = null
StyleFormat = sld
Styles = [StyleImpl[ name=epneige_color]]
StyleUrl = null
StyleVersion = null
Tiled = false
TilesOrigin = null
Time = []
Transparent = false
ValidateSchema = false
Version = 1.1.1
ViewParams = null
Width = 256

Comment: Its very difficult to say without debug information. Does it work OK in geoserver (e.g. in layer preview)? Do you see anything in the geoserver logs? Does the network view in your browser show a successful download? Does that download look like what you expect?

Comment: Also, where are the `transparent` and `format` options coming from?

Comment: @BradHards Yes everything looks fine in geoserver layer preview and the download is ok too.  Everything is on the map and it shows correctly the layer on Cesium. The network shows a successful download and nothing wrong in the geoserver logs. The only thing is that it shows jpeg format but maybe it need to be a png format but I don't know how to change that.

Comment: Try `image/png` instead of `image/jpeg`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a transparent image you need to ask for a PNG image rather than a JPEG as those don't support it.